# Checking Array element using if condition

Tags: php, mysql

Checking Array element using if condition.

```
 $investor_array = explode(",",$project[project_investor_id]);

                       foreach ($investor_array as $investor) {

                           echo $investor;

                            if($investor!==$user_data['id']){

                                 header('Location: error.php');
                                 exit;
                             } 
                       }
```

Please let me know how this make work if the $investor_array is like 1,26,29,30,39,48
and my $user_data['id'] = 26

Updates:
On my app investor can login and see their project. But they can check other project by changed the ID like

```
 http://192.168.1.100/srscrm/project-details-user.php?project=34
```

Thank You

Comment: Where is your problem? I'm sorry, but I'm really not understanding your question.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. The code you have will indeed redirect if any item in the array is not equal to $user_data['id']. You may want to check the `in_array()` function.

Comment: Right now it not working with multiple investor id. This code i am using if a investor dont have to access a project it will show a error page. This is to prevent some investors taking other investors project by changing id in URL.

Comment: Get rid of your loop, use `in_array($user_data['id], $investor_array)`

Comment: @briosheje The problem here is that there is no question. He only wants people to explain that piece of code...

Comment: @Ander2 : all right, was that clear in any way? :P

Comment: @Banna360 what is the purpose of your update? is that a second question/concern? what exactly are you asking, in your update?

Comment: to prevent to see project use `base64_encode()`  and `base64_decode()` ..so the your project id is encrypted..and it become little secure.

Comment: Sorry for my English. I want investors see error page is they take another investor project page ;)

Comment: you mean if invester change project id then the error page is display?

Comment: @DS9 thank you for the TIP ;) from now onward i am using the TIP :))

Comment: see my answer for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use PHP's in_array function http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

```
$investor_array = explode(",",$project[project_investor_id]);
if(!in_array($user_data['id'], $investor_array)){
   header('Location: error.php');
   exit;
}
```

Comment: @Banna360 I had to edit the code in the "if" statement about 30 minutes ago. doublecheck that it fits the logic you are trying to achieve. If it doesn't, can you clarify what you're trying to do and/or what logic error or error messages you're getting?

Comment: @Banna360 Please don't use phrases like "not working" when talking to fellow programmers. Be specific. If you want a specific answer, ask a specific question.

Comment: yes this piece of code working. Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

It you want to check if the element is in the array, use this function:

`bool in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = FALSE ] )`
http://php.net/manual/de/function.in-array.php

Answered your question?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
$project="34";
$pro_id=base64_encode($project);
http://192.168.1.100/srscrm/project-details-user.php?project=$pro_id
```

and on second page

decode using this:

```
$pro_id=base64_decode($project);
```

if investor type 34 in url then it is decoded and hence investor has nothing to see.

Comment: Yes this is nice idea. I am rewriting my code to this method.